# Brownie: Constructor Sequence has incorrect length, expected 1 but got 0?

Tags: contract-deployment, web3.py, brownie

Following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ?t=18945 (timestamped for your convenience!)

When I run `brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network rinkeby` I get back

```
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 12, in main
    deploy_fund_me()
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 7, in deploy_fund_me
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account})
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 600, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 507, in deploy
    data = contract.deploy.encode_input(*args)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 629, in encode_input
    data = format_input(self.abi, args)
  File "brownie/convert/normalize.py", line 20, in format_input
    raise type(e)(f"{abi['name']} {e}") from None
ValueError: constructor Sequence has incorrect length, expected 1 but got 0
```

Wut mean ser's?

Scripts/deploy.py:

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account


def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account})
    print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")


def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

Scripts/helpful_scripts.py

```
def deploy_simple_storage():
    # account = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
    account = get_account()
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
    stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(stored_value)
    transaction = simple_storage.store(15, {"from": account})
    transaction.wait(1)
    updated_stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(updated_stored_value)


def get_account():
    if network.show_active() == "development":
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

Comment: Can you provide the Solidity contract code?

Comment: https://github.com/GoGetterMeme/brownie_fund_me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this solidity code:

https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/brownie_fund_me/issues/1

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;
    address public owner;
    AggregatorV3Interface public immutable priceFeed;

    constructor() public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
        require(
            getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD,
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        );
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
        return priceFeed.version();
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }

    // 1000000000
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        // minimumUSD
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
        uint256 price = getPrice();
        uint256 precision = 1 * 10**18;
        // return (minimumUSD * precision) / price;
        // We fixed a rounding error found in the video by adding one!
        return ((minimumUSD * precision) / price) + 1;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);

        for (
            uint256 funderIndex = 0;
            funderIndex < funders.length;
            funderIndex++
        ) {
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        funders = new address[](0);
    }
}
```